# How to get all the paginated channels from Twilio chat using RxJava2?

Tags: android, twilio, rx-java2, twilio-api

Trying to get all the channels from Twilio chat using the twilio SDK. Want to wait for the channel list to load(using Observables) and then display it in my UI. Below is a rough idea of what i'm trying to do:

```java
private List<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> getAllChannels() {
  ChatClient.Properties props = new ChatClient.Properties.Builder()
        .createProperties();

  ChatClient chatClient = ChatClient.create(context.getApplicationContext(),
        accessToken,
        props,
        null);

  List<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> channelList = new ArrayList<>()

  chatClient.getChannels().getUserChannelsList(new CallbackListener<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> firstPaginator) {
      channelList.add(firstPaginator);
      Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> nextPaginator = firstPaginator;

      while (nextPaginator != null && nextPaginator.hasNextPage()) {
            nextPaginator = loadNextChatChannelPage(firstPaginator);
            if(nextPaginator != null) {
              channelList.add(nextPaginator);
            }
      }
    }
  });

  return channelList;
}


public Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> loadNextChatChannelPage(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> paginator) {
    paginator.requestNextPage(new CallbackListener<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> channelDescriptorPaginator) {
            return channelDescriptorPaginator;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            return null.
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: There's not really a question here. Is this working? Are you getting an error? Is something unexpected happening?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the question was how to do all of that in RXJava2, posted my solution below in case someone finds it useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is this:

```
/**
* Start loading the Twilio chat channel pages
*
* @return Single containing a list of all the chat channel pages
*/
public Single<List<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>> loadAllChatChannelPages(ChatClientManager chatClientManager) {
    return Single.create(emitter -> chatClientManager.getChatClient().getChannels().getUserChannelsList(new CallbackListener<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> channelDescriptorPaginator) {
            if(channelDescriptorPaginator != null) {
                emitter.onSuccess(channelDescriptorPaginator);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            String errorMessage = "";
            if(errorInfo != null) {
                errorMessage = errorInfo.getMessage();
            }
            emitter.onError(new Throwable(errorMessage));
        }
    })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(firstPaginator -> {
        if(firstPaginator != null) {
            return loadChannelPaginator((Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>) firstPaginator).toList()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        } else {
            return Single.error(new Throwable("Could not get chat channels"));
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Recursively loads the chat channel pages and returns them as a single observable
 *
 * @param paginator this needs to be the first chat channel paginator from the chat client
 * @return Observable containing a flattened version of all the available chat channel paginators
 */
private Observable<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>> loadChannelPaginator(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> paginator) {
    if (paginator.hasNextPage()) {
        return Observable.mergeDelayError(
            Observable.just(paginator),
            loadNextChatChannelPage(paginator)
                .flatMap(this::loadChannelPaginator));
    }

    return Observable.just(paginator);
}

/**
 * Loads a single chat channel page
 *
 * @param previousPage the previous page of chat channels
 * @return Observable containing the next chat channel page
 */
private Observable<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>> loadNextChatChannelPage(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> previousPage) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> previousPage.requestNextPage(new CallbackListener<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> channelDescriptorPaginator) {
            if(channelDescriptorPaginator != null) {
                emitter.onNext(channelDescriptorPaginator);
            }
            emitter.onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            if(errorInfo != null) {
                String errorMessage = errorInfo.getMessage();
                Timber.e(errorMessage);
            }
//                emitter.onError(new Throwable(errorMessage));
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }));
}
```

In the above code loadAllChatChannelPages loads the first paginator.

If that's not null then loadChannelPaginator takes over and recursively grabs each next paginator by executing loadNextChatChannelPage, a method that returns an observable for each single paginator.

Then mergeDelayError flattens all the paginators and returns them as one single Observable.

Finally in getAllChannels i apply Observable.toList(), this return a Single containing the list of Paginated chat channels that i needed.